# Single request with many ResultSets vs many requests with one ResultSet each?

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns

I have a Java Web Application using Spring MVC. The objects usually have lists of other objetcts as their properties. We build the objects using a single query returning multiples ResultSets, and treat it in the DAO.

Example: My Deck has a list of cards.

```
public class Deck{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private List<Card> cards;

   //Constructor and Getters & Setters
}

public class Card{
   private int id;
   private String name;
}
```

To build it we use a query thar returns a ResultSet for the deck properties, and other ResultSets to build the cards and put the list in the deck.

```
Deck deck = null;

List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
this.ps = this.conecction.prepareStatement("SP_SELECT_DECK ?");
this.ps.setInt(1, 1);

boolean isResultSet = this.ps.execute();

int nResult = 0;

do{
    if(isResultSet){
        this.rs = this.ps.getResultSet();

        while(this.rs.next()){
             switch (nResult) {
         case 0:
                     //Build the deck using the ResultSet
             deck = new DeckBuilder().newInstance(rs);
             break;                                      case 1:
                     //Add a new card built using the resultset
             cards.add(new CardBuilder().newInstance(rs));
             break;
         }
    }

        this.rs.close();
   }else{
       break;
   }            
   nResult++;
} while (this.ps.getMoreResults());

deck.setCards(cards);
```

Is this the better practice? Or is it better to do a query with the deck informations, return to the java application and call another query to fill the list of cards?

The question is about Patterns, Good Practices, Performance and Network Traffic

Comment: Having a result set where the first row is from one table (one Class) and the rest of the rows are from another table (another Class) is a horrible solution and shouldn’t be used unless you have some serious issues with performance. Any refactoring or other change in the design in the future could become a nightmare to implement because of this solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It was a solution we found to fill the objects with only one Database call. But we don't know if would be a problem to call the database more than one time in the same HTTP request to fill the objects separately and couldn't find any objective material on the internet.